# Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Here is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");

    struct element{
        int value;
        char activity;
    };

    typedef struct element element;
    element a;
    printf("%d",feof(fp));
}
```

Now if I don't give the last `printf` command it does not give me a segmentation fault, but if I give it `printf` it gives me a seg fault. Why?

I got the answer to my prev problem, now i have another problem

i had .txt appended to my input file in my makefile. Now i have another problem. on command make it gives error.

```
0make: *** [a.out] Error 1
```

why?

Comment: fopen() fails and so returns 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the return value of `fopen` (well, check the return value of *any* call), it probably failed to open the file.

Comment: yeah, i had .txt appended in my makefile.

Now i have another problem. on command
`make`

it gives error.
0make: *** [a.out] Error 1 why?

Answer (score 1):

Because you do not specify the file in a command line arguments, or because the file you have specified there could not be opened for some reason. In that case, `fopen` returns `NULL`, and when you pass that `NULL` to `feof` it crashes the program. You have to check return values and error codes, especially when functions may return `NULL`.

The correct code may look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Please specify the file name.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror ("Cannot open input file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf ("%d\n", feof (fp));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```